# Doctrine doesn't set parent reference in child entity created through API POST

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, fosrestbundle, jmsserializerbundle

### The situation

We're developing a REST API built on Symfony 3 with Doctrine and FOSRestBundle, using JMS for entity (de)serialisation.

The problem arises during a POST action, where we create a new entity (Team) with a collection of new child entities (Players). The JSON data is properly deserialised - a Team object is created and all the child entities are deserialised into Player objects in the players-collection within the Team object.

### The issue

After deserialisation, the Player objects do not have a Team-reference. Because of this, we can't store the Player objects because the required Team FK is empty.

We currently set the Player -> Team relationship "manually" in a PrePersist event:

```
/**
 * @ORM\PrePersist
 */
public function doSetParentRelation()
{
    foreach ($this->getPlayers() as $player) {
        $player->setTeam($this);
    }
}
```

in Team.php:

```
/**
 * @var \AppBundle\Entity\Player[]
 *
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Player", mappedBy="team", cascade={"persist"})
 * @Type("array<AppBundle\Entity\Player>")
 * @Groups({"create-version"})
 * @Assert\Valid(traverse="true")
 */
private $players;
```

in Player.php:

```
/**
 * @var \AppBundle\Entity\Team
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Team", inversedBy="players", fetch="EAGER")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
 * @Exclude
 */
private $team;
```

I'm wondering if there's a more elegant approach to this. Rather than having to add a custom PrePersist event to every entity with OneToMany relations that are created through an API call, we'd like a more global workaround.

Comment: Same problem using PUT verb.

Answer (score 1):

We've found a solution that works for us and doesn't rely on custom PrePersist events. We've set up JMS to use getters and setters rather than reflection for (de)serialisation:

```
use JMS\Serializer\Annotation\AccessType;

/**
 * [...]
 * @AccessType("public_method")
 */
class Team
{
    [...]
}
```

Then we added a setPlayers() method and altered the addPlayer() method to also set the team-reference in each Player.

```
/**
 * Set players
 *
 * @param Player[] $players
 */
public function setPlayers(array $players)
{
    foreach ($players as $player) {
        $this->addPlayer($player);
    }
}

/**
 * Add player
 *
 * @param Player $player
 */
public function addPlayer(Player $player)
{
    $this->players[] = $player;
    $player->setTeam($this);
}
```

Comment: Note: with that solution, I also had to add a setId() to the Team class.

Answer (score 0):

For POST requests to API's we use forms to take the request parameters and create entities or perform actions. (Note, you always have to submit the form on the backend because a user does not. See the `submit` method calls below.)

```
$yourEntity = new YourEntity();
$form = $this->createForm(YourFormType::class, $yourEntity)
             ->submit($request->request->all())
;

if ($form->isValid()) {
    // your entity logic
}
```

Or, depending on what your post consists of you may need to decode it first.

```
$yourEntity = new YourEntity();
$form = $this->createForm(YourFormType::class, $yourEntity);
$data = json_decode($request->getContent(), true);
$form->submit($data);

if ($form->isValid()) {
    // your entity logic
}
```

The only difference with this and a regular form is you just never create the form on the front end (through a twig template) with `$form->createView();`. You're just always catching the POST request and using the form as an entity transformer.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Answer relevant for form usage but not for JSON usage as indicated in the question (even though they use POST).

Comment: Incorrect. A form can handle JSON, one just needs to submit the request data. As I stated in this answer.